# Mongo DB BI Connector locally with remote db

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, mongodb-biconnector

I'm trying to create an ODBC connection with a remote mongoDB in order to connect MS Power BI with this mongo via ODBC.

By reading the mongoDB Connector documentation here ([https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/#:~:text=The%20MongoDB%20Connector%20for%20Business,Tableau%2C%20MicroStrategy%2C%20and%20Qlik](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/#:%7E:text=The%20MongoDB%20Connector%20for%20Business,Tableau%2C%20MicroStrategy%2C%20and%20Qlik)) - Hosted Database and On Premises BI Connector, i am trying to connect to the remote mongodb with the --mongo-uri option when you start the BI Connector's mongosqld process.

here is the response i am receiving on this connection attempt:

[If you can't see the image, the error is "unable to load mongodb information: failed to create admin session for loading server cluster information... socket was unexpectedly closed: EOF"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYE4T.png)

Does anybody know what i am missing on this connection?

Comment: If you are connecting to Atlas, a common reason is you need to use TLS/SSL

Comment: Were you able to connect it?